# unexpected behavior with printf()

Tags: c, printf

I tried to exercise with function in C as I managed to use a recursive function in C++ so here's my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Fctr(int n)
{
    return (n <= 1) ? 1 : n * Fctr(n -1);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char s_n[100];
    int i_n;

    printf("Factorial to calculate : ");
    fgets(s_n, 100, stdin);

    i_n = atoi(s_n);

    printf("The factorial of %s is equal to %d\n",s_n, Fctr(i_n));

    return 0;
}
```

Weird thing is that the output is the following :

```
Factorial to calculate : 5
The factorial of 5
 is equal to : 120
```

I compiled using GCC 5.3.0 with the following command :

```
gcc -o main main.c && ./main
```

I didn't even typed a \n between %s and the rest of my code. What's wrong with my second printf() ? I tried using %c instead of %s even tho it's a bad idea and it was indeed...

Comment: Newline is stored in buffer you pass to `fgets`.

Comment: Is there a solution to prevent this kind of behavior ?

Comment: Yes. Remove the newline. You'll have to search for it and replace it with `'\0'`. Don't assume that there is a newline character in the string.

Comment: @Gradiuss: you have to trim out the \n from input

Comment: To trim, use http://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/2410359

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excerpt from `man fgets` on my PC:

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and
>   stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an
>   EOF or a newline.  **If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer**.
>   A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in
>   the buffer.

That's what happens. You'll have to check for newline and remove it on your own, preferably replacing it with ASCII NUL (0, or '\0').

Comment: Thanks for adding the man, could you also suggest a correction ?